# Pandas: How to add columns to a superset from a subset of the superset?

Tags: python, pandas

In these codes, `In [15]: df4['t']=2` didn't apply to `df3`. This is not what I want. I want  adding columns action be applyed to `df3` too, instead of just be applied to `df4`.(However `df4['t']=2` didn't add a column named t but add a row, which confused me)

In Addition, I noticed that it hinted `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`.

Any idea to solve this problem?

```
In [6]: df2 =pandas. DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.222512 -0.907183  0.516238 -1.307885  1.604694
1 -0.648315  0.024165  0.487837 -0.374203 -0.193131
2  0.961563  1.847492 -1.773695 -0.791906 -0.458998
3  0.550847  2.221003  0.197836 -1.260352  0.794854
4 -0.211655  0.555512  0.832657 -0.703831 -0.586403
5 -0.384389  1.622995 -0.858065 -0.455278 -1.354076
6 -0.331782  1.256876 -1.080412  1.425681  0.017413
7 -1.008093  0.914414  2.023874 -0.004319  0.733349
8 -0.038734 -0.771304 -0.644371 -0.492886  2.111187
9 -2.812306 -1.434702 -0.074720  1.413066 -0.160265

In [8]: df3=df2

In [9]: df3
Out[9]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.222512 -0.907183  0.516238 -1.307885  1.604694
1 -0.648315  0.024165  0.487837 -0.374203 -0.193131
2  0.961563  1.847492 -1.773695 -0.791906 -0.458998
3  0.550847  2.221003  0.197836 -1.260352  0.794854
4 -0.211655  0.555512  0.832657 -0.703831 -0.586403
5 -0.384389  1.622995 -0.858065 -0.455278 -1.354076
6 -0.331782  1.256876 -1.080412  1.425681  0.017413
7 -1.008093  0.914414  2.023874 -0.004319  0.733349
8 -0.038734 -0.771304 -0.644371 -0.492886  2.111187
9 -2.812306 -1.434702 -0.074720  1.413066 -0.160265

In [10]: df3['d']=1

In [11]: df3
Out[11]:
          0         1         2         3         4  d
0  0.222512 -0.907183  0.516238 -1.307885  1.604694  1
1 -0.648315  0.024165  0.487837 -0.374203 -0.193131  1
2  0.961563  1.847492 -1.773695 -0.791906 -0.458998  1
3  0.550847  2.221003  0.197836 -1.260352  0.794854  1
4 -0.211655  0.555512  0.832657 -0.703831 -0.586403  1
5 -0.384389  1.622995 -0.858065 -0.455278 -1.354076  1
6 -0.331782  1.256876 -1.080412  1.425681  0.017413  1
7 -1.008093  0.914414  2.023874 -0.004319  0.733349  1
8 -0.038734 -0.771304 -0.644371 -0.492886  2.111187  1
9 -2.812306 -1.434702 -0.074720  1.413066 -0.160265  1

In [12]: df2
Out[12]:
          0         1         2         3         4  d
0  0.222512 -0.907183  0.516238 -1.307885  1.604694  1
1 -0.648315  0.024165  0.487837 -0.374203 -0.193131  1
2  0.961563  1.847492 -1.773695 -0.791906 -0.458998  1
3  0.550847  2.221003  0.197836 -1.260352  0.794854  1
4 -0.211655  0.555512  0.832657 -0.703831 -0.586403  1
5 -0.384389  1.622995 -0.858065 -0.455278 -1.354076  1
6 -0.331782  1.256876 -1.080412  1.425681  0.017413  1
7 -1.008093  0.914414  2.023874 -0.004319  0.733349  1
8 -0.038734 -0.771304 -0.644371 -0.492886  2.111187  1
9 -2.812306 -1.434702 -0.074720  1.413066 -0.160265  1

In [13]: df4=df3.loc[:,'d']

In [14]: df4
Out[14]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: d, dtype: int64

In [15]: df4['t']=2
C:\Users\jiahao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

In [16]: df4
Out[16]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
t    2
Name: d, dtype: int64

In [17]: df3
Out[17]:
          0         1         2         3         4  d
0  0.222512 -0.907183  0.516238 -1.307885  1.604694  1
1 -0.648315  0.024165  0.487837 -0.374203 -0.193131  1
2  0.961563  1.847492 -1.773695 -0.791906 -0.458998  1
3  0.550847  2.221003  0.197836 -1.260352  0.794854  1
4 -0.211655  0.555512  0.832657 -0.703831 -0.586403  1
5 -0.384389  1.622995 -0.858065 -0.455278 -1.354076  1
6 -0.331782  1.256876 -1.080412  1.425681  0.017413  1
7 -1.008093  0.914414  2.023874 -0.004319  0.733349  1
8 -0.038734 -0.771304 -0.644371 -0.492886  2.111187  1
9 -2.812306 -1.434702 -0.074720  1.413066 -0.160265  1

In [18]:
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple misunderstandings here. The statement `df4=df3.loc[:,'d']` returns a **Series** and not a **DataFrame**. So df4 is now a Series. Series don't have columns. They have values referenced by an index. The brackets operator attempts to find the index of your Series. Your following statement `df4['t'] = 2` adds the index `t` to the Series and assigns it the value 2.

It is possible to have df4 stay a DataFrame by using a list of column names sent to `.iloc` like this: `df4=df3.loc[:,['d']]`. df4 would now be a DataFrame and running command `df4['t'] = 2` would now append a column to df4.

You are getting the setwithcopy warning it appears that the statement `df4=df3.loc[:,'d']` may not make a new copy of the column d and so df4 may still reference it. However, `df4=df3.loc[:,['d']]` appears to be completely independent DataFrame and adding a column to it will not create the warning and also not modify d3 which will have to be done with an additional line of code.

Comment: So there is no way to make a "pointer" to a part of a dataframe, right? If I have to modify part of a dataframe, I have to modify the origin one directly.

Comment: This would be a pretty bizarre thing to do and would generate the settingwithcopy warning and not work.